# detect when the width/height of a <object> element is changed

Tags: javascript, object, resize, height, width

I'm debugging some php + javascript code, mostly yui.

There is a video on the page using an  element.

Just after the page is loaded, the object's width and height are adjusted. I can literally see it being resized.

It only happens in IE9...

There's a ton of Javascript. I'm using the developer tools in IE9....

I can watch the values in developer tools eg:

```
document.getElementById("myvideo").clientWidth;
document.getElementById("myvideo").clientHeight;
```

But I can't pause when the values are changed.

I've tried stepping through pressing F11 but its starting to send me a little bit nuts...

Any suggestions on how I can detect what code is resizing the object?

Answer (score 0):

Sort of answered it - there is a feature in Firebug "break on attribute change" - but its not available in Firebug lite :(

[Firebug lite - break on attribute change - IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079577/firebug-lite-break-on-attribute-change-ie)